# How to make child RecylerView Vertical Scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing the nested recyleview ,my view contains two recylerview and both have to scroll vertically as per implemetation , but i am facing the problem when i start scrolling the child recylerview then parent recylerview start scrolling.

What i need , when i scroll child recycle view then parent recycle should not scroll and when i start parent recycle to scroll then child should not scroll.

My parent recycle is white box that contains order id 997 ,then 996 and so on .

My child recycle is the box below the repeat button which contains and item for order id 997 is taurus 2518-10 chakka , taurus 3118 - 12 chakka and below this two there is three four more item which we are not able to see, that can be seen when user scroll up.
[image: Snapshot]

I had tried:

**On Parent Layout :**

```
materialRecylerAdapter = new MaterialRecylerAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<OrderPogo>) myOrderArrayList,nextFragmentFlag);
            WrappingLinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager= new WrappingLinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(materialRecylerAdapter);
```

**OnChildLayout:**

```
WrappingLinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager= new WrappingLinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        truckRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        myOrderTruckAdapter = new MyOrderTruckAdapter(context,newTruckList);
        truckRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        truckRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        truckRV.setAdapter(myOrderTruckAdapter);

        truckRV.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
                // Handle on touch events here
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow Parent RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                        Log.e("ACTION_DOWN","ACTION_DOWN");
                        recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow Parent RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                        Log.e("ACTION_UP","ACTION_UP");
                        recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: why you want to have RecyclerView inside RecyclerView and both should scroll Vertically?

Comment: @LalitPoptani because the box you are seeing below repeat button ,contains many item on it ,so user can scroll it vertically to see the content , and there is one more parent box which is splitted by divider .

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are setting `ChildRecyclerView` from `onBindViewHolder` of Parent Adapter if you are not setting from `onBindViewHolder`, then please set it from `onBindViewHolder`.

Something like this..

**ParentAdapter onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mChildRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayout(context));
    holder.mChildRecyclerView.setAnimation(null);

    //scroll vertically
    holder.mChildRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    ChildAdapter childAdapter = new ChildAdapter(context);

    //setter Method of ChildAdapter to set Data
    childAdapter.setList(parentDataList.get(position).getChildList());

    //set childAdapter
    holder.mChildRecyclerView.setAdapter(childAdapter);
}
```

This is how I'm setting my ChildAdapter. hope work with you too.

Comment: ChildView is still remain unscrollable

Comment: try by removing `NestedScrollingEnable`

Comment: can you giv me some code on gmail so that i can follow the step

Answer (score 0):

Disable nested scrolling for `RecyclerView`.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: when child is scrolled then parent recylerview is not going to be scrolled so that i made child recylerview to true, if child is getting scrolled then parent recylerview ,i set it to false here :ecycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);